# Why magento "continue" button doesn't work?

Tags: magento

I've changed permission from 750 to 755 for folders and set 644 for files
Nothing else seems to be wrong but can not continue with magento1.9 installation

wondering what is the problem ?[image]

Comment: did you try creating the media folder? and the var folder as sometimes when they are missing Magento struggles to create them... I understand you do have write permission so it should create those folders automatically